# CGContextSetFillColorWithColor error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I am confused why my app is crashing with this error.

I have implemented the displayLayer method (for rendering CALayer).
The first time this method runs things work fine. But subsequent calls to this is when the error occurs.

The error seems to occur when the self.bgColor is being set to the context fill color.
INTERESTINGLY... if I create the bgColor right before that line, things work. But as it stands, the bgColor is being created upon initialization of this class (the container of the displayLayer method).

```
-(void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)caLayer
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(caLayer.frame.size);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.bgColor);
  CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 25)); 
  [self drawText:context];
  // get image buffer
  UIImage *imageBuffer = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  // set layer contents to image buffer
  caLayer.contents = (id)[imageBuffer CGImage];
}
```

Comment: oh my god, sorry about the scrunched up code snippet!!

Comment: To format your code, use four spaces at the start of each line, or use the button with the 1's and 0's on it which does it for you

Comment: How are you setting bgColor? Could you please post that code snippet? I suspect you're not retaining it, and use an autoreleased color. The first time displayLayer is called is probably in the same runloop, so the color hasn't been released yet. Then the runloop ends, bgColor gets released, and in subsequent calls to displayLayer: you get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Comment: in my header file i have this line, CGColorRef bgColor; Initially i did not create a property for this. Then i decided to give it a property... @property (nonatomic) CGColorRef bgColor;

Note that it does like this property being defined as retain because  it's not an object type.

Comment: And in my class' init method i assign a value for the bgColor... bgColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done much iPhone programming yet, and never used a CGColor instance variable, so what I would do is this:

```
@interface {
    ....
    UIColor *bgColor;
    ....
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *bgColor;
...
@end

@implementation
@synthesize bgColor;
- (id)init {
    ...
    self.bgColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    ...
}
-(void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)caLayer {
    ...
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.bgColor.CGColor);
    ...
}
...
@end
```

[UIColor blackColor] returns an autoreleased object, and you assigned it to your instance variable without retaining it.

Using self.bgColor instead of just bgColor in init and having set up the property to retain its value will make sure that the color is retained and can be used in displayLayer later on.

As I mentioned I don't have any experience with using CGColors directly, that's why I'm using a UIColor in the above code. Please adjust as needed.

Comment: Hmmm....the whole thing between self and non using self is apparantly not quite solidified in my mind. But what you just said makes sense to me. I've already adjusted to use UIColor* instead of CGColor.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: synthesize bcColor will generate two methods: -(UIColor *)bgColor and -(void)setBgColor:(UIColor *)aColor;. These methods handle retaining and releasing the objects. Using self.bgColor = xxx is equivalent to calling [self setBgColor:xxx] and using xxx = self.bgColor is equivalent to calling xxx=[self bgColor], so all the retaining and releasing is taken care of. If you directly read or modify the instance variable (without self), you'd have to do the retaining and releasing yourself.

Comment: The sweet spot on this answer is the use of self.bgColor.CGColor to grab the CGColorRef val for a UIColor IMHO

Comment: @Thomas Müller Thanks Thomas. I have been tearing my hair out, over this. It turned out that I had set the property affinity attributes incorrectly. \@property (nonatomic, assign) UIColor *bgColor; -> \@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *bgColor; solved it. I never knew these attributes made so much difference...